# What is the security efficacy of 'fillable'?

Tags: laravel

I'm struggling to fully understand the security efficacy of `fillable` and wondering what to do with columns that can't have a default value and will never be provided by the user.

> A mass assignment vulnerability occurs when a user passes an unexpected HTTP request field and that field changes a column in your database that you did not expect. For example, a malicious user might send an is_admin parameter through an HTTP request, which is then passed to your model's create method, allowing the user to escalate themselves to an administrator.

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#mass-assignment

The above snippet from the documentation contains a good example: `is_admin`. That value wouldn't be directly provided by the user but it still needs to be provided during `create()`.

Another example might be `slug`. This would likely come from a user-provided `title` value. This can't have a default value and won't be provided by the user so it needs to be `fillable`.

As far as efficacy goes, doesn't it make sense for there to be a class of secured input that's identified as (1) not being provided by the user and (2) is fillable? It seems like a column loses its secure-by-default status if it's listed in `fillable`.

Comment: The fillable property will make sure that the columns that are not included in the array, cannot be mass-assigned. So if you use the create method, and you pass the whole request post data, only the fields in fillable will be added in the db. If the user tampers the post data, he cannot edit fields (like is_admin). I personally do not use mass assignment at all. You can also add validation to prevent users from  changing values that they should not change. If you have fields that don't have a default value, and are not provided by the user, don't use mass assignment for that model.

Comment: @GertB. Then I don't understand mass assignment. Are you saying create() allows for the raw request to be used as input? I would never do that. One must always validate data first.

Comment: Yes, you always validate your request. also when using mass assignment. The warning is there because some people think that if they validate the fields that are in the form, that makes it safe. you also need to make sure the user does not add fields to the request. Instead of checking the array you pass to the create method yourself, you can use the fillable property. It's just an easy way of handeling this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fillable prevents batch assignment. Disables the use of arrays. Thus, it is protected from external attacks.

Example:

You can protect the is_admin column:

```
$fillable = ['name', 'password', 'email'];
```

Then, to be able to update or create the value, you must explicitly set the value in the model and save it, for example:

```
 $user->is_admin = 1;
 $user->save();
```

Comment: I understand now. Thank you. Being so new, I was unaware of the save() method.